# $f,\hat f\in L^1(\mathbb R)$ implies $f\in L^p(\mathbb R)$ for $1\leq p\leq\infty$

Tags: measure-theory, fourier-analysis, convolution, fourier-transform

Could someone please hint how I may show $f,\hat f\in L^1(\mathbb R)$ implies $f\in L^p(\mathbb R)$ for all $p\in[1,\infty]$?

This is what I tried:

$$\begin{align*}\int\left|f\left(x\right)\right|^pdx&=\int\left|\int\widehat{f}\left(\xi\right)e^{2\pi i\xi}d\xi\right|^pdx\\&\leq\int\left(\int\left|\widehat{f}\left(\xi\right)\right|\left|e^{2\pi i\xi}\right|d\xi\right)^pdx\\&\leq\int\left(\int\left|\widehat{f}\left(\xi\right)\right|d\xi\right)^pdx\\&=\int\left\|\widehat{f}\right\|_1^pdx.\end{align*}$$

However, the integral does not converge if $\left\|\widehat{f}\right\|_1\neq0$. Moreover, I am not sure how to use the assumption that $f\in L^1\left(\mathbb{R}\right)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the Fourier inversion, under the assumption $\hat f\in L^1$ we get $f$ back as the inverse Fourier transform of $\hat f$, and estimating the integral defining this transform yields $\|f\|_\infty \le C\|\hat f\|_1$  (the constant $C$ is subject to normalization choices for $\hat f$). So we know $f\in L^1\cap L^\infty$. For any $1<p<\infty$,
$$
\int |f|^p \le \|f\|_\infty^{p-1} \int|f| = \|f\|_\infty^{p-1}\|f\|_1  <\infty
$$
(One could say this is a kind of interpolation, but certainly not anything deep like Riesz-Thorin.)

Comment: I get everything except for how you could estimate $\|f\|_\infty \le C\|\hat f\|_1$.

Comment: I think I got it. Now I'm unsure about $C$.

Comment: Looks like $C=1$ with your Fourier convention where $f(x) = \int e^{2\pi i \xi} \hat f(\xi)\,d\xi$

Answer (score 1):

if f and $f$ and $\hat f$ in $L^1$, then $f$ is in $L^\infty $ and $f$ is in $L^2$ (Plancherel), then by Riesz-Thorin interpolation theorem, we can extend the continuité of the Fourier operator to $L^p$ space.

Comment: I fail to see how Plancherel is used.

Comment: if $f$ is in $L^1$ then $\hat f$ is in ${L^\infty }$ (obvious) then we have $|\hat f| \leqslant C$, we mulyiply by $\hat f$ we get $|\hat f{|^2} \leqslant C|\hat f|$, so $|\hat f{|_{{L^2}}} \leqslant C|\hat f{|_1} < \infty $, and we repeat the same process with $f$.